# PCL Save Image File to local File System

Tags: cross-platform, xamarin, storage, portable-class-library

I am looking for a way to store image files in my local filesystem using the **PCL Storage** plugin in my core Project for `Windows Phone`, `Xamarin.Android` and `Xamarin.iOS`. 
However, the plugin does just provide methods for writing Text. Nothing about bytes.
Is there a way to save byte arrays?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
IFile file = await FileSystem.Current.GetFileFromPathAsync(fs.filepath);
byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
using (System.IO.Stream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
{
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, 100);
}
```

Edit: Some code taken from http://pclstorage.codeplex.com/

```
IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("myfile.abc", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Once you've got the IFile object you should then be able to use this in the same way:

```
IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("myfile.abc", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
using (System.IO.Stream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
{
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, 100);
}
```

Comment: This will be quite useful later for opening the file.
Right now i'm looking for a way to actually write it.

Comment: I tried your solution and it is creating files with same byte size, I have given byte size byte[3500], so all images are creating with 3500 byte size while images size varies.

Comment: @Ashish Jain where 100 is in stream.write(), replace with buffer.length.

Answer (score 3):

You can also check out Paul Betts ' Splat library for cross platform image loading/saving.

https://github.com/paulcbetts/splat

Comment: Looks nice, but didn't find the way to save images cross-platform. Have you guys?

Answer (score 0):

To take a picture and store it with date and time on it, I used a combination of:

1. Plugin.Media
2. Plugin.Media.Abstractions
3. PCLStorage
4. SkiaSharp

I found this [Using SkiaSharp, how to save a SKBitmap ?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/75958/using-skiasharp-how-to-save-a-skbitmap) and used it as a base for this:

```
// I get my bitmap from the camera (Plugin.Media allows to pick it from filesystem too)
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
    Directory = "MyFolder",
    Name = "MyPic001",
    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium,
    CompressionQuality = 40,
    SaveToAlbum = true
});
// If succesfully taken...
if (file != null)
{
    // Start using SkiaSharp to write text on it
    var bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(file.Path);
    var canvas = new SKCanvas(bitmap);
    var font = SKTypeface.FromFamilyName("Arial");
    var brush = new SKPaint
    {
        Typeface = font,
        TextSize = Convert.ToInt64(40),
        IsAntialias = true,
        Color = new SKColor(255, 255, 255, 255)
    };
    // Write on top of the image
    canvas.DrawText(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"), 10, 60, brush);
    var imageSK = SKImage.FromBitmap(bitmap);
    // Get rootFolder and FileName from Plugin.Media's file.Path
    string A = file.Path;
    string P = A.Substring(0, A.LastIndexOf("/"));
    string F = A.Substring(A.LastIndexOf("/") + 1, A.Length - (A.LastIndexOf("/") + 1));
    // Start using PCLStorage
    IFolder rootFolder = await FileSystem.Current.GetFolderFromPathAsync(P);
    IFile myFile = await rootFolder.GetFileAsync(F);
    // Use PCLStorage file opening to create an IO.Stream
    using (Stream s = await myFile.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
    {
        // Use SkiaSharp SKImage and SKData to Save the image+text on file.Path
        SKData d = imageSK.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg, 40);
        d.SaveTo(s);
    }
}
```